# How to run more than one django sites using same virtual environment as subdirectories in apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, django, mod-wsgi

I have an unmanged vps. I have 3 django sites sitename_dev, sitename_staging, sitename_live which are run using a virtual env. All 3 are default django instances with no changes made. I have configured my apache as follows.

in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/wsgi.conf`

```
#from virtual env
LoadModule wsgi_module "/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so"
WSGIPythonHome "/path/to/virtualenv"

# dev site
Include /path/to/sitename_dev.conf

#staging
#Include /path/to/sitename_staging.conf
```

in `path/to/sitename_dev.conf`

```
WSGIScriptAlias /sitename_dev /path/to/sitename_dev/sitename_dev/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/sitename_dev

<Directory /path/to/sitename_dev/sitename_dev>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

in `path/to/sitename_staging.conf`

```
WSGIScriptAlias /sitename_staging /path/to/sitename_staging/sitename_staging/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /path/to/sitename_staging

<Directory /path/to/sitename_staging/sitename_staging>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

With this config **my.ip/sitename_dev/** opens.
But if I uncomment the staging site line, to include the staging site in /etc/apache2/conf-available/wsgi.conf, both **my.ip/sitename_dev** and **my.ip/sitename_staging** give 500 error. How can i run 3 sites as subdirectories ?

`specs:
    OS: ubuntu 16.4 LTS
    server: apache2 2.4.18 
    python version of virtual env & wsgi: 3.6`